# c - updating integers with pointers and addresses

Tags: c, pointers, printing

So the function below should be adding 1 to n and printing out the updated n each time scanf reads a 1.
Yet It is not updating and keeps printing out 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void add_one(int *n);
void command(int x);
int
    main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i;

    while (scanf("%d", &i) == 1){
        command(i);
    }
    return 0;

}

void add_one(int *n){
    int i = *n;
    i++;
    *n = i;
     printf("%d\n", i);
}

void command(int x){
    int n = 0;

    if (x == 1){
        add_one(&n);
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense what you are attempting to do. You have several unnecessary variables.

Comment: you are copying `i` by value into command, then creates a local variable, in commands scope, sets it to 0, then counts it up by one. or returns.  since `n`is not global it is deleted every single time command is finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `n` as a local variable in `command`. Every time you call `command` from `main`, it starts at `0`. One way to fix it is to move the declaration to `main` and pass it to `command`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void add_one(int *n);
void command(int x, int *n); /* second parameter added */
int
    main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i, n = 0;   /* n added */

    while (scanf("%d", &i) == 1){
        command(i, &n);  /* &n added */
    }
    return 0;

}

void add_one(int *n){
    int i = *n;
    i++;
    *n = i;
     printf("%d\n", i);
}

void command(int x, int *n){
    /* int n = 0;   declaration moved to main */

    if (x == 1){
        add_one(n);  /* removed & since parameter n already is a pointer */
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but passing one more parameter will add _kind of_ overhead, while a simple `static` would have done the job in a more subtle way. :-)

Comment: `static` in a function should be used with care. Having state in a function limits its usefulness. Like the `strtok` function where you can only split one expression at a time. Really annoying in a threaded application.

Comment: @NatashaDutta: Practically speaking, passing two variables adds no more overhead than passing one.  Adjusting a stack pointer by 8 bytes isn't any slower than adjusting it by 4, using two registers isn't any slower than using one, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass x instead of n

```
  if (x == 1){
        add_one(&x);
  }
```

Or you have to initialize n with x and pass n. For example

```
  int n = x;
  if (x == 1){
        add_one(&n);
  }
```

Though in my opinion your complicated code with a chain of function calls does not make a great sense.:)

It seems you mean the following

```
void add_one(int *n){
     printf("%d\n", ++*n);
}

void command(int x){
    static int n = 0;

    if (x == 1){
        add_one(&n);
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the declaration of n inside function command with storage specifier `static`.

Comment: or make `n` a global variable, or also create `n` where `i`is created and pass it by reference all the way through the chain of calls..

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you change the following code in the if (x == 1) closure body:

```
add_one(&n);
```

To:

```
add_one(&x)
```

Comment: This will print `2` each time `1` is entered.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `int n = 0;`, `n` is local to the function `command()` and have *automatic* storage duration, hence every call to `command()` will get to see a *new* `n`. The computed value won't be *retained*.

Solution: Either

1. define `n` as `static`.
2. make `n` a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Do you want `command` to update the value of `i` in `main`?  If so, then you'll have to pass a pointer to `i` to `command`:

```
while ( scanf( "%d", &i ) == 1 )
  command( &i );
```

Which of course changes the definition of `command`:

```
void command( int *x )
{
  if ( *x == 1 )
    add_one( x );  // x is already a pointer
}
```

Note that the `i` variable in `add_one` is superfluous; you can simply write

```
void add_one( int *n )
{
  *n += 1;
  printf( "%d\n", *n );
}
```

If you *don't* want `command` to update `i` in `main`, then you'd pass `i` as you're doing now:

```
while( scanf( "%d", &i ) == 1 )
  command( i );
```

and the change to `command` would be

```
void command( int x )
{
  if ( x == 1 )
    add_one( &x );
}
```

This updates the parameter `x` in `command`, but since `x` is *local* to `command`, it doesn't affect `i` in `main`.